# Account merge leaves behind empty network profile

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, network-profile, merge-accounts

I recently merged two of my Stack Exchange accounts. This causes the user with the higher ID to be deleted on each site where I had accounts that got merged. Except it *doesn't* remove the **network** profile of the older account. Here's what my [hallowed out network profile looks like](https://stackexchange.com/users/17341075/smitop). There's nothing there: no accounts or reputation or activity. Ideally, this page should redirect to [my new post-merge network profile instead](https://stackexchange.com/users/13986849/smitop).

This behaviour has confused fans of mine who have bookmarked my network profile to be able to keep up with my Stack Exchange activity, network-wide: I learned about this issue when one of my fans expressed their confusion to me.

Comment: We don't ever redirect user profile URLs after a merge. Network profiles can be a bit weird. Sometimes they just start pulling profile info from the new account. If they worked like profiles do on regular sites, it'd just become a 404 after a merge.

Comment: @animuson Is it the same as deleted network profiles, where it's deleted within 24 hours once it syncs again unless the user has signed in there directly and as such has a physical profile there?